# Permalink Settings in WordPress for Category

Tags: wordpress, seo, settings, categories, permalinks

i have a quick question about Permalink Settings in WordPress.
My current setting for post is
`http://somesite/%postname%/`

I want same for my category, how can i make my category URL to `http://somesite/%categoryname%/`

The default in WordPress is `http://somesite/category/%categoryname%/`

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Questions about WordPress development and administration should be asked on [wordpress.se].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can just put a period in the **"Category base"** field in your permalink settings. If you are using the Yoast SEO plugin you can use the Advanced area to change the permalinks also.